# Gitlab API: Problem with Unittesting Issues, Projects and Login

Tags: c#, gitlab, xunit, gitlab-api

I have to write some unit tests for a college project which is based on the gitlab api. A few weeks ago we had to change our login function as our old one didn't work anymore and switched to https://www.gitlab.com/oauth/token. This thing works now, however it messed up all our tests and I can't get them to run anymore.

There are now differences between calling a method from the tests and calling it from the controller.

For example calling [https://www.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{projectId}](https://www.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/%7BprojectId%7D) containes a JsonObject called "Permission" when the method is called from the controller however it doesn't have it when I call the exact same method with the exact same values from the test.

```
public async Task<int> GetAccessLevelOfUserForProject(string token, int projectId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"GitlabService::GetAccessLevelOfUserForProject Token: {token} projectId: {projectId}");

            var project = await rest.Get<GitlabProjects>($"https://www.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{projectId}",
                          new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Authorization", $"Bearer {value}" });
            int aLevel = 0;
            if (project.Permissions.Project_access != null)
                aLevel = project.Permissions.Project_access.Access_level;
            else if(project.Permissions.Group_access != null)
                aLevel = project.Permissions.Group_access.Access_level;

            return aLevel;
        }
```

When I want to login I always get an 401 unauthorized with the Content `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed due to unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method."}` although it uses the same method as the other login which works and it also uses the same client authentication.

```
public async Task<string> Login(LoginDTO login)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"GitlabService::Login username:{login.Username}");
            var client = new RestClient($"{baseUrl}/oauth/token");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator({clientusername}, {clientpassword});
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", $"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddParameter("username", login.Username);
            request.AddParameter("password", login.Password);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GitlabTokenData>(response.Content);
            return data.Access_token;
}
```

Replace {clientusername} and {clientpassword} with your client authentication.

There are even more cases where things like this happen and I don't understand why. Maybe someone who is more comfortable with this topic can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab do be weird sometimes. There is actually a difference between calling https://www.gitlab.com/api/v4/... and https://gitlab.com/api/v4/... If you call gitlab with a www it will redirect your request to gitlab.com, however it drops all your headers (with the token inside) and so you will always get the answer as if you wouldn't even have given it a token in the first place.[image: Calling www.gitlab.com]

vs.
[image: Calling gitlab.com]

It is really hard to figure out why. When you happen to be in the same situation just take out Burp Suite Proxy and intercept the requests by setting the proxy in your HttpClient's constructor. I hope this could help somebody in the future who made the same oversight as me.